# Recursively invoke lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am writing a voting system using lambdas. There is one lambda for submitting votes, and another for aggregating totals. This allows for a lot of concurrent voters without the need to re-compute the total after every submission.

I'm using [serverless](https://serverless.com) to publish REST endpoints to AWS API gateway.

The problem I'm trying to sidestep is the execution timeout limit. The API gateway has a limit of 30s, which is too low for my use-case.

So my approach is to simply have the lambda call itself again. There are plenty of examples around, but I can't get mine to work. It always returns with `{"message":"Forbidden"}`

I have tried `lambda.invoke` as well as POSTing to the endpoint using request (`request.post(endpoint)`). In both cases, I get the same error message, saying it's forbidden.

The role has AWSLambdaFullAccess, so I'm confused about why it's forbidden from within AWS, but totally open to the rest of the world.

---

**Update**

I had the wrong permission applied to the role: `AWSLambdaInvocation-DynamoDB` where it should have been `AWSLambdaFullAccess`. At least I can use `lambda.invoke` now.

Still not sure why the REST endpoint is failing. There is currently no auth required to use these endpoints.

There isn't much to the serverless config, but here it is.

```
service: project-name

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  region: us-west-2
  timeout: 6 # The default is 6 seconds. Note: API Gateway current maximum is 30 seconds
  memorySize: 512
  role: arn:aws:iam::510967681306:role/lambda_basic_execution

functions:
  aggregate:
    handler: handler.aggregate
    events:
      - http:
          path: aggregate
          method: post
          cors: true
```

Comment: FYI DynamoDB has atomic counters.

Comment: Why is your Lambda function taking longer than 30s? For good user experience, it should return in under one second. What is taking the time?

Comment: trigger your lambda from cloudwatch.

Comment: Could you provide your function's code and serverless template's code? Would be helpful for investigation..

Comment: Do you have an auth system in-place? You probably get Forbidden because you bypass the auth system when trying to call itself again.

Comment: Another thing, why would an aggregation of totals take more than 30s?

Comment: Aggregation isn't taking 30s. It's a rolling update, which provides info to users about how the whole group is voting during the 1-2 minute process. Atomic counters are neat! I may use those in the future, but for this use-case, the users aren't locked in to a particular vote, so accumulation is not as helpful. I toyed with the idea of sending an SNS message to trigger the func, but I'd rather just invoke directly.

Comment: @positlabs although there are valid cases for it, it's not clear how "calling itself again" is helpful in this case... API Gateway does not handle streaming responses... it's strictly *en bloc*, and waits until the response is *complete* before returning.

Comment: I don't need the results of the lambda to stream back to the caller. I only want to kick off the process. I am invoking the lambda callback before the subsequent lambda responds. Otherwise, I'd hit the execution timeout every time.